# Connecting to aws s3 using private key(generated from pem file)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to connect to s3 bucket from the EC2 instance. The logging into ec2 instance is using private key, generated from pem file. Ideally I should have been able access the s3 bucket from here directly without passing access key and secret. But when i try to connect it is asking for above 2 things rahter than directly connecting and listing the contents.

Comment: no wonder  this site is going down.. qns get downvoted unnecessarily. filled with loosers..

Comment: Did you manage to work it out? I'm having the same issue right now

Answer (score 0):

The SSH key you generated from the pem file, and the AWS IAM account access key and secret key are two completely different things. The SSH key is used for initiating SSH connections with your EC2 server. The access key and secret key are from an AWS IAM account and are used for accessing the AWS API.

If you are trying to access S3 from your EC2 server the the prefered way is to assign an IAM role to the EC2 instance with the appropriate permissions, so that you don't have to deal with the IAM key credentials.

Comment: There is an IAM role assigned to the EC2 machine with access all on the S3 buckets. I have to access the s3 from ec2 without having to use the access and secret key. the moment i type command "aws ls s3.... " it asks me to run "aws configure" and wants me to set those 2 keys.

Comment: I think you just need to run `aws configure` and leave the keys blank, if the IAM role is indeed assigned to the EC2 machine already.

Comment: did that. didn't help